# In Google Sheets how to compare date formats of multiple cells using Apps Script / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I was searching for a way to compare date formats of 2 different cells and validate them.

A SO user showed me some code. We changed it in order not to use the confusing (for me) regex syntax so the user came up with something like this:

```
const getDateFormats = range =>
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getActiveSheet()
    .getRange(range)
    .getNumberFormats()
    .flat();

const main = () => {
  const formatsInRange = getDateFormats('A1:A3')
  console.log(formatsInRange);
  formatsInRange.forEach((format, i) =>
    'dddd", "d" "mmmm" "yyyy' === format ||
    'dd"/"mm"/"yyyy' === format
      ? console.log(`Value ${i + 1} is OK`)
      : console.log(`Value ${i + 1} is not OK`)
  )
};
```

So the code above will work for 2 and 3 cells: `getDateFormats('A1:A2')` and `getDateFormats('A1:A3')`.

[image]

[image]

But if I try with 4 cells or multiple cells all the way down the column with `getDateFormats('A1:A4')` or `getDateFormats('A1:A')` the console displays this error:

[image]

I would like to understand why this happens and what needs to be changed in order for the console to display multiple results like it does for 2 or 3 cells.

My file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ExXtmQ8nyuV1o_UtabVJ-TifIbORItFMWjtN6ZlruWc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Umm, that's not an error. What made you think that's an error? Given the code, what was the output you were expecting? The first console log just prints out all the formats, like it's being asked. Ran your code on my end: https://imgur.com/a/evwFnYm

Comment: Oh f* you're right. It's working. You see yesterday I think the consoles is ok is not ok etc wasn't showing. Something changed or I was just tired and f*ed up. Sorry.

Comment: LOL that's OK, happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer of the question is on the comments, leaving this answer as community wiki:

The code provided was working as expected and returned the proper result.

The asking user commented that:

> Oh you're right. It's working. You see yesterday I think the consoles is ok is not ok etc wasn't showing. Something changed or I was just tired. Sorry.